# When developing a Strapi plugin, is there a way to develop "live" without having to build the plugin each time?

Tags: npm, plugins, strapi

I'm working on a Strapi plugin.

I would like to know if, by chance, there would be a way to be able to "live" develop it - I mean; having my Strapi backend detecting changes made in the plugin's code without having to `npm run build` it each time.

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is.

You can run the command -

```
npm run develop --watch-admin
```